# How to put border around a legend in R?

Tags: r, plot, border, legend

I m using R to plot legend but i need to draw black border arnd it.

```
plot.new()
legend(x=0,y=.15, c(" legend1"), cex=1,pt.cex =1.4,col=c("green"),bty="n",fill="green", pch=c(15, 15, 15, 17),border="black")
legend(x=.75,y=.15, " legend", cex=1, pt.cex =1.4,bty="n",col=c("black"), pch=c(17), border="black")
```

But in the above code, no black border printed as expected in image shown below. How can i

[image]

put border(here black border covering greeen box) and legend as shown below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course there is no border! You have used `bty = "n"`

From `?par` (search for "bty" on that page):

> bty: A character string which determined the type of box which is drawn about plots. If bty is one of "o" (the default), "l", "7", "c", "u", or "]" the resulting box resembles the corresponding upper case letter. A value of "n" suppresses the box.

Either remove the `bty` argument or specify on of the alternatives that match the shape of the border you want.

---

Update based on question edits.

Since you want to control the fill color and border of your `pch` symbols, try this:

```
plot.new()
legend(x=0, y=.15, "legend1 ", cex=1, pt.cex=1.4, 
       bty="n", pch=22, col="black",
       pt.bg="green")
legend(x=.75,y=.15, "legend 2", cex=1, pt.cex =1.4, 
       bty="n", pch=24, col="red", pt.bg="white")
```

The key is to use one of the `pch` values that can be colored and filled with different colors, which are those in the range of 21 to 35.

From `?pch`, the options we have are:

> - pch = 21: filled circle
> - pch = 22: filled square
> - pch = 23: filled diamond
> - pch = 24: filled triangle point-up
> - pch = 25: filled triangle point down

Comment: I need border around sqare and triangle not enlsoing all legends.I m using using border=black but still there is no border.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot.new()
 legend(x=0,y=.15, c(" legend1"), cex=1,pt.cex =1.4,col=c("green"),
         bty="o",fill="green", pch=c(15, 15, 15, 17) )
 legend(x=.75,y=.15, " legend", cex=1, pt.cex =1.4,
         bty="o",col=c("black"), pch=c(17), box.col="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using open plot symbols. I think this should be what you are looking for:

```
plot.new()
legend(x=0, y=.15, "legend1", 
       cex=1, pt.cex =1.4, bty="n", pch=22, pt.bg = "green")
legend(x=.75, y=.15, "legend2", 
       cex=1, pt.cex =1.4, bty="n", pch=24, pt.bg = "black")
```

Check out [this short help page](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_R%3a_plot) for further `pch` examples.